# Are our dreams associated with our past or future?

Tags: dream

There are certain situations in my daily life which seems like I had dreamt of them before. Also sometimes I get dreams regarding my past which are blend of two different situation which can never be true(totally vague/random). Are these an indication about something or something to be neglected?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

> There are five types of dreams:
>
> 1. The first type of dream is that which comes up in the form of your cravings and desires.Your unfulfilled desires come up in dreams as
>      fulfillment. Have you experienced this? You want to drink water and
>      you say, 'Not now.' You want to eat ice cream, pizza and you say, 'Not
>      today.And then you go to bed and in your dreams you munch or eat pizza
>      and you have a big scoop of ice cream. You wanted to go for a walk
>      with somebody, your boyfriend or girlfriend, and you could not do it
>      and in your dreams you find yourself going on a walk, going on a boat
>      and skiing in the mountains. All these are your latent desires which
>      come up in dreams. Desires and fears come up as dreams.
> 2. The second type of dream is related to stress released from past experiences (which could come up). All that you have experienced in
>      life comes up as dreams.
> 3. The third type of dream is an intuitive dream. You get an intuition of what might happen in the future.
> 4. The fourth type of dream is a mixture of all these four types.
> 5. The fifth type of dream has nothing to do with you; it is to do with the place you are sleeping in. You are sleeping in a hotel in
>      Italy and in the dream, you experience all the Italian sounds coming
>      and all those strange languages. How many of you have experienced
>      this? You hear people's dialogues which are in a completely different
>      language; you have no idea what it is. But still, you continue to see
>      all those things happening. This is to do with the place (space)
>      there.
>
> So these five types of dreams can occur. And the thing is, you do not
>   know which one is what. Usually, it is the fourth type of dream which
>   is a mixture of all these (types of dreams). So you cannot really
>   distinguish and say, ‘This is my intuitive dream.’ It could be; it
>   need not be. So a wise person would simply brush them all aside.
>   Anyway, it is of no use. It is only a dream.
>
> Even this waking reality is a dream. Now you are all sitting here,
>   tomorrow you will be somewhere else and next week all this will be a
>   dream. What you would do next week is a dream right now. Your mind is
>   more in a dream than it is awake.

From an [article](http://www.artofliving.org/in-en/yoga/patanjali-yogasutra/knowledge-sheet-37) by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar

Answer (score 1):

Some dreams are associated with future like the dream that the [Pandava army soldiers saw](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10008.htm)

> On other days, O sire, the foremost warriors of the Pandava camp used to see in their dreams that figure leading away the sleeping combatants and Drona's son smiting them behind! The Pandava soldiers saw that lady and Drona's son in their dreams every night from the day when the battle between the Kurus and the Pandavas first commenced. Afflicted before by Destiny, they were now smitten by Drona's son who terrified them all with the frightful roars uttered by him. Afflicted by Destiny, the brave warriors of the Pandava camp, recollecting the sight they had seen in their dreams, identified it with what they now witnessed.